# Why number is getting out of long long range in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector, data-structures, long-integer

Given two non-negative integers num1 and num2 represented as string, return the sum of num1 and num2.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> addToArrayForm(vector<int>& A, int K) {
     int i=A.size()-1;
     vector<int> result={};
     long long int no=0;
      for(int x:A)
      {
          no=no+x*pow(10,i);
          i--;
      }
      no=no+K;
      if(no==0)
          return {0};
      while(no>0)
      {
          long long int r=no%10;
          result.push_back(r);
          no=no/10;
      }
     reverse(result.begin(),result.end());
     return result;
     
    }
};
```

I am getting this error with long long.

Line 9: Char 14: runtime error: 1e+19 is outside the range of representable values of type 'long long' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:18:14

Comment: `A` can be of arbitrary size. Your compiler is telling you that this function will generate overflows if A is ever larger than 19 elements.

Comment: Also note that [`pow` is a dangerous way of computing integer powers](/questions/33187956/c-pow-unusual-type-conversion)

Comment: Yea I will work on an optimized solution now

Answer (score 2):

Provided that `long long` is implemented by a signed 64-bit integer, 1e19 is indeed out of the positive range of that type. The maximum representable value of that type would be 9223372036854775807.

As to whether 1e19 is a possible value, it is because it depends on the size of the vector `A` that you pass as input. You may want to limit your algorithm to only accept `A` of up to a certain size by adding a check against [`std::numeric_limits<long long>::digits10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10).

Answer (score 0):

maybe initialise `std::vector<long long int> result` will solve your problem. Because you defined it as an integer, but you pusing back long long variable.

or you can use `static_cast<type>` to convert types temprorary for ongoing alegorithm (cppref: [static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast))

disclaimer: I answered, because I can't comment (I don't have 50 rep)